# How to efficiently update a field in Firestore from Google Sheets

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with Google Sheets, and I am trying to send data to my Firestore database. I have been able to write to Firestore from Google Sheets, but I can't seem to update a field without completely messing things up.

This is my current testing code:

```
function getFireStore() {
  const email = "your@email.gserviceaccount.com"
  const key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n your key here \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  const id = "project_id";

  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, id);
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()

  var data = {
    numIndividuals: sheet.getRange(23, individuals).getValue(),
    numTeams: sheet.getRange(23, teams).getValue(),
    schoolID: sheet.getRange(23, schoolID).getValue(),
    uid: sheet.getRange(23, uid).getValue(),
  };

  firestore.createDocument("competitions/" + sheet.getRange(23, compId).getValue() + "/registration/abcdefg", data)

}
```

I understand after playing around with this that it will create a new subcollection titled "registration" with the document "abcdefg." The same thing happens when I use the `updateDocument` function, as well.

For the website that is reading and writing to this particular Firestore database, I use a similar function `.update()` to update the document with the correct information. However, in Google Sheets, while it would work the same way it is much more convoluted and tedious to do so.

The way that I came up with for trying to update the document was basically copying everything and adding in the new data.

However, this is seriously tedious and messy. Just copying the data that isn't changed looks like this:

```
var data = {
    compDate: competitions.fields.compDate.stringValue,
    contact: competitions.fields.contact.stringValue,
    email: competitions.fields.email.stringValue,
    grade: competitions.fields.grade.stringValue,
    id: competitions.fields.id.integerValue,
    maxTeams: competitions.fields.maxTeams.integerValue,
    regDate: competitions.fields.regDate.stringValue,
    schTeams: competitions.fields.schTeams.integerValue,
    schedule: competitions.fields.schedule.stringValue,
    site: competitions.fields.site.stringValue,
    status: competitions.fields.status.stringValue,
    timestamp: competitions.fields.timestamp.integerValue,
    user: competitions.fields.user.stringValue,
    year: competitions.fields.year.stringValue,
  }
```

The data I want to change is a `.mapValue` with multiple `fields` where one of the fields can have multiple fields, which also have multiple fields.

Here's the hierarchy for the field I need to update:
[first registration and first team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC2hX.png)

I know I could do multiple for-loops and whatnot on this, but my question is: is there a simpler way to do this, or do I have to go through and loop over everything to extract only what I want?

As a sidenote, what gets sent to Firestore if I put in the data I got from Firestore using the spread operator, without any editing, it includes every child from the above image. As in, I would have `registration -> mapValue -> fields -> 0 -> mapValue -> fields -> etc.` And, I don't want those mapValue and fields included, just that actual data (i.e. `registration -> 0 -> {schoolID, uid, names, etc.}`).